# C++11 - Way to detect the operator new[]

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I'm trying to make something like this work:

```
struct holder {
  std::function<void()> destroyer;

  template<typename T>
  holder(T) = delete;

  template<typename T>
  holder(std::enable_if< WAS CREATED WITH new > pointer) {
    destroyer = [=] { delete pointer; };
  };

  template<typename T>
  holder(std::enable_if< WAS CREATED WITH new[] > array) {
    destroyer = [=] { delete[] array; };
  };

  virtual ~holder() {
    destroyer();
  };
 };
```

In a way that I could then simply make `return new test;` and `return = new test[10];` on a function that would return `holder`. But I found out that it won't ever be treated as an array, as `operator new[]` returns a pointer.

Is there any way to achieve the desired result?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Are you trying to reinvent [`unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)? `unique_ptr<int> p(new int);` will call `delete` when `p` goes out of scope. Similarly, `unique_ptr<int[]> p(new int[10]);` will call `delete[]`.

Comment: Kinda, but with an implicit detected `<template type>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is impossible; whether or not `new` or `new[]` was used is not part of the pointer's type information.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know of is through *placement-new*:

```
#include <new>
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    void* operator new(std::size_t n, void* ptr)
    {
        std::cout << "operator new()\n";
        return ptr;
    }

    void* operator new[](std::size_t n, void* ptr)
    {
        std::cout << "operator new[]\n";
        return ptr;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A* ptr;
    new (ptr) A();
    new (ptr) A[5];
}
```

Comment: I mean, I understand it is a special example of usage, but things inside `main()` are so terribly wrong, it gives me shivers...